# Gulp and Bower - creating proper files structure

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower, main-bower-files

I'm adding Bower to project which is using Gulp already. My folder structure is like:

```
 |- bower_components
 |   |- dependency1
 |   |   |- dist
 |   |       |- lib1.js
 |   |       |- lib1.min.js
 |   |
 |   |- dependency2
 |       |- core
 |           |- sub
 |           |   |- extra.js
 |           |
 |           |- lib2.js
 |
 |- target
     |- js
```

I have already managed to copy all 3rd party libreries to target/js using [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) and [bower-normalize](https://github.com/cthrax/gulp-bower-normalize). But it's flatten (and I didn't set bower-normalize option `flatten` to true!), so it's looks like:

```
target
 |- js
     |- lib1.js
     |- extra.js
     |- lib2.js
```

Files `lib1.js`, `extra.js` and `lib2.js` are marked as `main` in bower.json config file.

What I would like to achieve is to have files structure like:

```
target
 |- js
     |- dependency1
     |   |- lib1.js
     |
     |- dependency2
         |-  sub
         |    |- extra.js
         |
         |-  lib2.js
```

I will be really greatful for help!

Comment: It might be helpful to show your gulpfile.js file, that way someone can help you with the syntax.

Comment: you need to pass `{base: '.'}` to your gulp.src command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go through [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten),
>   this will help you to remove or replace relative path for files. And
>   also, I highly recommend
>   [wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep). It automatically
>   handles all of your bower dependencies for you, as well as the order
>   of the dependencies. Hope this will help you.

**Your source directory with bower components:**

```
 |- bower_components
 |   |- dependency1
 |   |   |- dist
 |   |       |- lib1.js
 |   |       |- lib1.min.js
 |   |
 |   |- dependency2
 |       |- core
 |           |- sub
 |           |   |- extra.js
 |           |
 |           |- lib2.js
 |
 |- target
     |- js
```

Using gulp-flatten -

```
gulp.src(['bower_components/**/*.js'])
  .pipe(flatten({ includeParents: [1, 1]} ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
```

**will create this structure (from above tree directory):**

```
|- bower_components
|   |- dependency1
|   |   |- lib1.js
|   |
|   |- dependency2
|            |-  sub
|            |    |- extra.js
|            |
|            |-  lib2.js
```

`includeParents: [1, 1]` If passes as array of two numbers, both parents from top and bottom will be kept in resulting path of a file.

`includeParents: 1` If passed in as positive number, it will include the number of top-level parents in the output.

`includeParents: -1` If passed in as negative number, it will include the number of bottom-level parents in the output.